# Does react-data-grid support pagination? Cannot find it in the examples

Tags: react-data-grid

Is there any pagination support?
UI controls for previous and next page and also the input for page number so that user can jump right into the specified page?

Comment: No, there is no paging, the best u can had is only http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/#/examples/scroll-to-row-index